# Refresh an EmbeddedOLEObject Excel.Sheet.8 in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint-2007

I'm building an Access database which updates the data within a Powerpoint presentation - mainly charts, with the occasional bit of text.  All code is stored in Access, the problem is in the second procedure below.

Everything is working fine: I can open the presentation template, get the data from Access into the correct worksheets cells behind the embedded chart - I then have to manually edit the chart before it updates with the new data though.

I have a few procedures to do the work:

This first procedure cycles through each slide in the presentation and calls the correct procedure when certain shapes are reached:

```
Public Sub RefreshPowerPoint()

    Dim colPPT As Collection
    Dim oPPT As Object
    Dim oPresentation As Object
    Dim oSlide As Object
    Dim oShape As Object

    Set colPPT = New Collection
    Set colPPT = CreatePPT

    Set oPPT = colPPT(1)
    Set oPresentation = oPPT.Presentations.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\QC Review - Template.pptx")

    For Each oSlide In oPresentation.slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            If oShape.Type = 7 Then 'msoEmbeddedOLEObject
                If InStr(1, oShape.OLEFormat.progid, "MSGraph.Chart", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    'Debug.Assert False
                ElseIf InStr(1, oShape.OLEFormat.progid, "Excel.Chart", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    'Debug.Assert False
                ElseIf InStr(1, oShape.OLEFormat.progid, "Excel.Sheet", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Select Case oSlide.SlideNumber
                        Case 2
                            Refresh_TeamAccuracyMargins oShape
                        Case 3

                        Case Else
                            'Do nothing
                    End Select
                End If
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide

End Sub
```

This next procedure copies the data from the Access query into the embedded Excel sheet.
**The last few lines of the procedure show what I have tried to get the actual chart to update with the new data** - at the moment it's only doing it if I manually click 'Edit' at which point it suddenly realises there's new data.

```
Private Sub Refresh_TeamAccuracyMargins(sh As Object)
    Dim oWrkSht As Object
    Dim oWrkCht As Object
    Dim oLastCell As Object
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim x As Long

    Set oWrkSht = sh.OLEFormat.Object.Worksheets(1)
    Set oWrkCht = sh.OLEFormat.Object.Charts(1)

    Set oLastCell = LastCell(oWrkSht)
    With oWrkSht
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), oLastCell).ClearContents
    End With

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SQL_REPORT_MonthlyAccuracyTrends")
    x = 1
    With rst
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            x = x + 1
            oWrkSht.Cells(x, 1) = .Fields("sMonth")
            oWrkSht.Cells(x, 2) = .Fields("Accuracy")
            oWrkSht.Cells(x, 3) = .Fields("Inaccuracy")
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    Set oLastCell = LastCell(oWrkSht)

    With oWrkSht
        oWrkCht.SetSourceData .Range(.Cells(1, 1), oLastCell), 2
        oWrkCht.Activate 'Executes, appears to do nothing.
        oWrkCht.Refresh  'Executes, appears to do nothing.
        'oWrkCht.Update  'Not supported.
        'oWrkCht.Requery 'Not supported.
        'oWrkCht.Repaint  'Not supported.
        'oWrkCht.Parent.Refresh 'Not supported.
    End With

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

For completeness the two procedures use these functions to create an instance of Powerpoint and to find the last cell on the worksheet:

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : CreatePPT
' Date      : 02/12/2015
' Purpose   : References or creates an instance of Powerpoint and returns the
'             reference as the first part of a collection.
'             The second part indicates whether Powerpoint was referenced or created.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function CreatePPT(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim oTmpPPT As Object
    Dim bIsOpen As Boolean
    Dim colTemp As Collection

    Set colTemp = New Collection

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Powerpoint is not running. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpPPT = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    bIsOpen = True

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Powerpoint. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                                 '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
        bIsOpen = False
    End If

    oTmpPPT.Visible = bVisible
    colTemp.Add oTmpPPT
    colTemp.Add bIsOpen

    Set CreatePPT = colTemp
    Set colTemp = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreatePPT."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function



'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : LastCell
' Date      : 26/11/2013
' Purpose   : Finds the last cell containing data or a formula within the given worksheet.
'             If the Optional Col is passed it finds the last row for a specific column.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Object, Optional col As Long = 0) As Object

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        If col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , 1, 2).row
        Else
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(col).Find("*", , , , 2, 2).row
        End If

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that activating the correct slide and executing DoVerb updates the chart.

So, in my first procedure I update the call to the Refresh procedures with a reference to the Powerpoint application:
`Refresh_TeamAccuracyMargins oShape` becomes
`Refresh_TeamAccuracyMargins oPPT, oShape`

`Private Sub Refresh_TeamAccuracyMargins(sh As Object)` becomes
`Private Sub Refresh_TeamAccuracyMargins(oPPT As Object, sh As Object)`

I then activate the slide after updating the chart source data, so this block of code:

```
With oWrkSht
    oWrkCht.SetSourceData .Range(.Cells(1, 1), oLastCell), 2
End With
```

becomes

```
With oWrkSht
    oWrkCht.SetSourceData .Range(.Cells(1, 1), oLastCell), 2
    oPPT.ActiveWindow.ViewType = 7
    oPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GoToSlide 2
    oPPT.ActiveWindow.ViewType = 1
    sh.OleFormat.DoVerb (1)
End With
```

Apart from some screen flickering it now works - any idea on how to get rid of the screen flickering?